How does Bias affect the reliability of a process?
So my attempt is to define a process and test it on its reliability.
In a discussion, an argument was made that a consensus on the reliability of the process is needed for a process to be reliable.
Aka.: If not everyone agrees that the process is reliable, then it follows that the process is not reliable.
To give more context: In an answer/debate, I proposed a process (although not in great detail) and argued its reliability. One of the opposing arguments was that this process is not reliable because there are a lot of people/communities that would disagree that it is reliable.
EDIT
Since my debate partner made his position more clear in the comments:

"one way/factor to measure reliability is by checking how many people
who follow the same process agree on the conclusion."

I think this position still prompts the following question but deals better with the fallacy argument raised in the comments. But that's only my opinion.
END EDIT
The Problem I have with this is that people will have already drawn their conclusions, meaning if there is a process X with results [A, B, C,...], then people exist that assume that A is the correct solution. This means that if the process results in B, those people will be biased towards that process and will reject its reliability regardless.
E.g. climate change: There are various scientific methods, checking different things and many people therefore arrive at the conclusion that the is a climate change happening.
However, some people don't think that climate change is real and therefore question the reliability of the process used.
(Note: I don't want a debate about climate change. I am just using it as an example, feel free to use a more appropriate one)
So here are my questions:

Is there a difference between objective reliability and perceived reliability?
Can Bias even impact reliability? Is it even a good argument for/against the reliability that some people agree/disagree about the reliability of a process?
Can the reliability be measured by consensus? How is it factored in?
Is reliabilism even possible when dealing with greatly controversial topics?
When defining a process, how can potential biases be accounted for?

e.g.: Can I define a process, that determines the bias and in the end add some percentage to the Reliability of the process? Along the lines of this:
isClimateChangeReal (){
     determineBias(){
            AnswerQuestion("Do you think climate change can generally occur?")
            AnswerQuestion("Does Science have reliable methods to quantify climate change?")
            ...

            return Bias.
     }

     //Other Processes testing for Climate change
     return probabilityThatClimateChangeIsReal + Bias
}

The problem I do see with this is that it's difficult to determine the bias since the author of the process could also be biased.
So in general I am interested in how bias is dealt with in reliabalism.
EDIT
I think I should define what I mean by objective and perceived reliability.

Objective reliability: The degree to which a process, method, or system consistently produces accurate and dependable results, independent of individual opinions or perceptions.
Perceived reliability: The degree to which individuals or groups believe that a process, method, or system is reliable.


"an argument was made that a consensus on the reliability of the process is needed for a process to be reliable": an apparently fallacious argument, consensus cannot determine reliability any more than ideas determine reality, if reality means anything at all, or reliability...

"an argument was made that a consensus on the reliability of the process is needed for a process to be reliable" That's obviously false, and I suspect you misunderstood what the person was saying. More likely the person was saying that you cannot use the purported reliability of a process in an argument with them when they did not agree that the process is reliable. You have to use premises that the target of your argument agrees with.

@JulioDiEgidio-inactive While I agree with your position, it's not exactly obvious to me how to defend it. Maybe because I fail to see the argument behind the analogy to ideas determining reality. I mean if no one agrees that my process is reliable then how can I assert that it is, despite the disagreement?

@DavidGudeman In the debate the question was if there was a reliable process for a certain statement. After proposing one, his argument was, that many people would disagree that my proposed process is reliable, thus making it unreliable. (He had other arguments as well, but this one confused me)

If you're talking about what I said, then I didn't say/mean consensus on the reliability of the process is "needed", but rather one way/factor to measure reliability is by checking how many people who follow the same process agree on the conclusion. We have fallible minds, and what other people think can be a valuable resource in noticing flaws in your own thinking. And this isn't a fallacy (@JulioDiEgidio) - fallacies only apply to deductive reasoning, but we're quite limited in what we can soundly conclude about reality through pure deduction; this is an abductive/epistemic consideration.

@NotThatGuy I edited the question to better represent your position.

Similar case: Michaelson asserted that there is a Luminiferous Ether. Others said there is not. He tried for decades to prove that there was, and his own increasingly precise experimental results told him that there wasn't. He persisted in his belief anyway.

So I guess, based on this discussion here:  "1. Is there a difference between objective reliability and perceived reliability?" can be answered with "Yes, and perceived reliability does not determine objective reliability of a process" Is that fair to say?

To those who downvoted the question: What made this question worth downvoting? Not asking for a debate but I want to improve my future questions.

Climate change is contentious. If you don't want to debate it, don't mention it.

Getting downvoted because climate change is contentious is quite the measure of how useless is lurking around here...

I did not downvote, but I think the question would be better by citing sources for definitions. The forum is not meant for discussions like "this guy I met said..., but I think...". This forum is for questions like: "Aristotle said... but Newton said: ...". This forum discusses philosophy, not laymens squabbles about personal opinions. Now I have convinced myself to downvote.

Preface
If you're talking about what I said, then I didn't say/mean consensus on the reliability of the process is "needed", but rather one way/factor to measure reliability is by checking how many people who follow the same process agree on the conclusion. We have fallible minds, and what other people think can be a valuable resource in noticing flaws in your own thinking.
And this isn't a fallacy* - fallacies only apply to deductive reasoning, but we're quite limited in what we can soundly conclude about reality through pure deduction. This is an abductive/epistemic consideration.
* It's not a fallacy as used in this context. Of course "appeal to popularity" is a fallacy in deductive reasoning, but the way it's used here is different.
So in this answer, I'm addressing reliability of agreement, rather than agreement of reliability. That is, you measure the reliability of a process by seeing what different people conclude using that process. You don't conclude that a process is good by checking whether people agree on its reliability... but of course people can have a process (a meta-process, if you will) for determining the reliability of processes, and they reach conclusions about the reliability of a process using that meta-process, and then you can determine the reliability of the meta-process. But this is getting a bit convoluted. If someone wants to say a process isn't reliable, it's probably best to just ask them why they think that, and then evaluating what they say, rather than evaluating meta-process reliability.
Answer
Context
Let us formalise epistemic concern, the process, the input, the variables and the output.
First things first, we're talking about something approaching reliabilism, where a conclusion reached through some process is determined to be true or false by us based on the reliability of the process to reach that conclusion (and we can use reliability as the only consideration, or we can potentially include other considerations, and this might give some degree of confidence for truth).
Reliability can be defined as how often the process produces true results versus false results (or, if you want to get into solipsism and our inability to have complete justified confidence in the truth of anything, one can consider something like coherence or predictive power to evaluate truth).
One-mind reliability
So let's say some process P is used to reach some conclusions about some questions or claims.

You apply P using your mind M1, to evaluate question Q1, and you determine the conclusion to be C1a, in short:
P + M1 + Q1 = C1a (let's not think too much about the strict formal definitions of plus and equals in this equation, because the meaning of this equation is written out above)

Similarly, we can also evaluate other questions to reach other conclusions:

P + M1 + Q2 = C2a
P + M1 + Q3 = C3a
P + M1 + Q4 = C4a
P + M1 + Q5 = C5a

Now if you evaluate the truth of a bunch of these conclusions, you can determine the reliability of the process when applied by yourself. This reliability could then be used to determine the truth of a subsequent conclusion. There's nothing necessarily wrong with such a measurement.
But there are some potential issues:

Your mind (M1) has some variables that are hidden to your conscious mind (e.g. cognitive bias) that affects the conclusion you reach. For example:
This might specifically lead to you subconsciously favouring conclusion C5a for question Q5 above other possible conclusions, and this might lead to you unknowingly applying the process P improperly to be able to reach that conclusion. If you're using the reliability on other questions to say that C5a is true, that would be a problem.

You might consider various questions equally valid in applying the process to. But there might be some factor that makes some questions too different from others, such that the reliability of the process on one set of questions might not necessarily tell you much about the reliability of the process on some other question.
This isn't necessarily something reliabilism in itself takes into account, but we can consider a very simple example to demonstrate the problem: let's say you have a process which involves simply accepting that how someone says they got home is true. You evaluate this for many people, and every time you find it to be true: John says he drove his car home, and that he did. Sarah says she drove her bike, and that she did. Steve says he took the bus, and that he did. Now we try to apply this to another question: Drew says he teleported home using his portal gun. Should we believe him? Using the above process, with no other consideration, we'd have to just say "yes", but this is a fairly absurd conclusion. The differentiating factor is that all the other claims are mundane things that we know happens many, many times every day, whereas we have no evidence of the existence of portal guns or even the possibility of those or teleportation[citation needed]. So that's why we can trivially accept the others (at least provisionally), but not the teleport claim.

You might have a small sample size. A good general rule in statistics is: more data is better (although there are a lot of caveats to this).


So, can we improve on the reliability?
Multiple-mind reliability
Well, we can also consider other people using their minds to apply the process to various questions to reach various conclusions:

P + M2 + Q2 = C2b
P + M3 + Q2 = C2c
P + M4 + Q2 = C2d
P + M5 + Q2 = C2e
P + M2 + Q3 = C3b
P + M3 + Q3 = C3c
P + M4 + Q3 = C3d
P + M5 + Q3 = C3e
...

Now you have a whole lot of people all reaching conclusions about things using the process P.
This mitigates all of the problems mentioned above:

Other people may not share your cognitive biases, so this could mitigate the effect of cognitive bias.
But this doesn't tell you who has which bias and wouldn't account for a bias that's shared by everyone you include. One should also consider who you're including and which biases they may have.

You can determine an upper bound for reliability of the process P on one specific question by checking the conclusions that different people reach. In this case, you can't have a problem of some questions being too different from others, because it's the same question.
Of course, this in itself doesn't say much about whether the conclusion is ultimately true (because you'd need to already know whether it's true to determine the reliability of the conclusion each person reached). But if e.g. 40% of people agree on conclusion 1, 30% agree on conclusion 2, and 30% agree on conclusion 3, you can say the reliability of the process is at most 40%, according to this metric (with the minimum being 0%, in case none of those conclusions are correct).
Note: This is not to say this is an upper bound of the "true" reliability, but rather this is just another metric that estimates reliability (but only as an upper bound).

Other people can also consider whether there's some factor making some questions too different from other questions. This is mostly just general knowledge sharing, to potentially help you determine whether those questions are too different.

The sample size is much bigger.


The biggest potential issue I see is that you can't be entirely sure that they followed the process in the exact same way (and this could include them being dishonest). And they may also not have access to the exact same knowledge you have. But there are still a lot of potential benefits.
So that's basically why I think it's good to factor in what other people conclude using the same process, when determining reliability.
On your questions of biases
Is there a difference between objective reliability and perceived reliability?
Well, you'd need to have access to objective truth to determine objective reliability, and we don't have access to that.
The best we can do is subjective reliability.
Can bias even impact reliability?
See "some potential issues" above, for how bias can impact reliability.
Is it even a good argument for/against the reliability that some people agree/disagree about the reliability of a process?
No, not directly (unless you're measuring the reliability of people agreeing about reliability). See my note on "reliability of agreement, rather than agreement of reliability" above.
Can the reliability be measured by consensus? How is it factored in?
You can measure agreement per question, to determine an upper bound of reliability (as discussed above).
You can also just every combination of some person and some question, and average the known correctness of the conclusions they reach using some process, as one simple estimate of the reliability of that process.
This is neither prescriptive nor exactly and precisely defined: different people can reach different conclusions about how to factor consensus in when determining reliability.
Is reliabilism even possible when dealing with greatly controversial topics?
If there is too much disagreement, one can say reliabilism says there's no clear conclusion, one can say reliabilism is not useful here and some other method should be used, or one can focus on reliability metrics other than consensus. See also: my note about science below.
When defining a process, how can potential biases be accounted for?
This seems very broad, since we've identified many potential biases, and there could be many potential processes.
Some general red flags, I'd say, would be if people appeal to things e.g. "being obvious", "feeling wrong" or "being natural", in their process, to justify a conclusion, without being able to further justify that (one can debate the reasonableness of such a process based on reliability or other considerations).
In any case, I don't know that one can come up with some general way to define processes to avoid biases. It helps to be aware of biases, and often you might only spot biases in hindsight. That's probably the best advice I can offer here: always be open to the possibility that you might be affected by biases, explore that possibility honestly, and don't be afraid to be wrong (admitting you're wrong might not feel great, but it's far worse to keep being wrong while refusing to admit it).
On the topic of science
You mentioned climate change. For that, and for a few other science question, there seems to be a common pattern where the overwhelming majority of the scientific community agree on one conclusion, but there's much more disagreement among laypeople.
Clearly, for such an example, the scientific process (which may include formal education on a topic) could be deemed to be reliable in the sense that most people who follow it reach the same conclusion. Meanwhile, laypeople who don't follow the process don't reach the same conclusion, but they aren't following the process, so this doesn't apply to this metric.
Of course one could debate the merits of the process itself, and whether there are factors that differentiate questions. And of course people within the scientific community also disagree about various things. But those are separate questions.

"You can have determine an upper bound on the reliability ... if e.g. 40% of people agree...cannot said to be higher than 40%" => That assumes the people are not biased or the effect can be eliminated that way. I do grant you that you can eliminate individual bias but not group bias. In the climate example: If I ask 1 Million climate scientists then I get climate change is real by >80%. If I ask 1 Million climate critiques I get that it is not by >80% in this example the upper bound depends on the people I ask to use P. I agree with your other points though.

It would work a lot better with people who have no idea of the topic, but if given a topic where everyone has a stance, the bias potentially will influence every step of the process. In such a case randomly selecting people would also not work because you simply sort people by their background in a different way.

I might add that climate change is just an example with a strong stance on each side. We can pick another one. My point is simply that if we have Group A and B it follows P + A(Mn) + Q1 = C1a and P+ B(Mm) + Q1 = C2b  (n,m∈ℕ)

@telion Regarding "cannot said to be higher than 40%", I changed the wording a bit on that to reflect the fact that I'm just saying that specific metric is 40%, regardless of the method for determining that metric is good, and even though you might be able to come up with a higher reliability estimate using other methods (those would be things to also take into account).

@telion "It would work a lot better with people who have no idea of the topic" - of course people knowledgeable on a topic may have some confirmation bias or some other biases. But it would be difficult/implausible for someone new to the topic to properly evaluate a complex topic that is built on extensive amounts of knowledge via education, training and practical experience.

"checking how many people", that sounds awfully like the majority wins the truth battle. I'd prefer to see check how many and which different positions represented by other humans come to the same conclusion. E.g. if atheism and theism of multiple religions is compatible with a claim, that makes it more reliable. If some crazy cult disagrees, it does not hurt no matter how many there are.


an argument was made that a consensus on the reliability of the process is needed for a process to be reliable

It's an apparently fallacious argument, consensus cannot determine reliability any more than ideas determine reality, if reality means anything at all, or reliability... (ideas vs reality, aka the kids' fallacy, i.e. "it is if we say so".)

if no one agrees that my process is reliable then how can I assert that it is

What is the definition of "reliability" (in use)?  If there is one, then that determines if a "process" is "reliable", not anything else!  Indeed, de facto at least, there is no such thing as "perceived reliability": "satisfaction surveys" exist, but they provide feedback into the product, not into the definition of "reliability".
Of course, there can be disagreement even about definitions, even the technical ones, but that's then another issue: generally speaking, something being right/wrong (even de facto in this case), and somebody admitting that right/wrong, is just not the same thing...  --  Indeed just look at the other answers here, people just make stuff up, and even insist, on all channels, that it's philosophy that is not rigorous: aka the self-fulfilling prophecies, another by now ubiquitous, not to say institutionalised, fallacy.
Summing up, I think a direct answer to your question title simply is "it does not".

Your approach is wrong: strictly, reliability is impossible to foresee or predict. In simple words, you can say an assessment is reliable only if you have actual data to compare it against.
If you have a result without any reference, you can't know if a result is reliable. For example, say that the formula to calculate the distance to venus is:
d = ( 3 + 2 ) * 4 [million Km]    [1]

Without any other reference, is that reliable? You don't know. If now, we say that the actual result is 45 million Km, ONLY NOW you can say that formula [1] is not reliable.
So, don't try to assess reliability without actual references.
Regarding climate change, you cannot define a method/process that is reliable per se, by means of methaphysical (I mean rational) devices. You will only know if your method/process is reliable after gathering actual results.
Bias/subjectivity is not relevant. What your colleagues are suggesting it to assess reliability against other methods, but that mechanism loads a double bias to the assessment: those of the answers (if people believe that there is change) and that of the method (the belief that this method/process is reliable based not on actual data, but upon a secondary biased result, which loads an ad hominem fallacy).
In any case, just propose your method, focusing on excluding biases as much as possible. That wouldn't mean your method is not reliable, but that doesn't imply that the method cannot be better than others.


In a discussion, an argument was made that a consensus on the reliability of the process is needed for a process to be reliable.

Reliabilism at it's root is subjective, so each individual has the possibility and the rational responsibility to decide for themselves which process is reliable.
To use reliabilism in a debate for an argument, it is required first that all participants agree that reliabilism is appropriate for the given topic, and they also need to agree on the relative reliability of processes. Else a debate is not possible and parties can only agree to disagree.
Consensus and debate are typically seen as a way for the individual to come to better judgements as opposed to the individual just pondering issues without talking to anyone else about them.
This is not just the case with reliabilism, but also for all other forms of epistemology that I can think of.
So the question seems to be very little related to reliabilism, and more related consensus than reliabilism.


Is there a difference between objective reliability and perceived reliability?


Obviously, because individuals will count "truths" differently and thus rate reliability differently. Individuals may also use different ground truths.


Is reliabilism even possible when dealing with greatly controversial topics?


Reliabilism yes, but consensus no. So different parties will typically decide differently on the reliability of processes and thus a topic may remain controversial, because reliabilism is subjective.


When defining a process, how can potential biases be accounted for?


Treatment of biases seem to be a question for Skepticism rather than process reliabilism. Process reliabilism would only state that if a process p1 can be replaced with another process p2 having less biases, than we'd expect p2 to yield truths more often and prefer beliefs based on p2 over beliefs in p1. Other than that, biases are accepted in reliabilism pragmatically as unavoidable error in decision making that cannot be helped until a better process can be found.
As an example, one might see both naturalism and superstition both as biases, yet one might judge that naturalism as a bias leads to more truths (and less delusions) than superstition, and thus prefer a process biased with naturalism than one biased with superstition. That would be in line with reliabilism.
Also note that biases are not necessarily making processes less reliable. As an example, naturalism as a bias can be seen as having improved the reliability of science in history compared to other biases for dealing with the unknown. As an example for the black death raging in Central Europe in the 14th century having a the unknown cause, some were biased to believe that the process had naturalistic causes requiring naturalistic solutions. Many of those with superstitions instead blamed the Jews, persecuted them and committed massacres (typically against official statements of the church). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persecution_of_Jews_during_the_Black_Death
So reliabilism would not necessarily seek to eliminate all biases, but rather compare the relative benefits of different biases in producing truth more often. Typically we consider the word "bias" in a negative way as introducing errors into judgement (and typically that's the effect of biases), but bias can also sometimes help to "tip the scales" towards truth in particular where without any bias no decision would be possible.
Biases are treated with much more caution in the scientific method in particular when setting standards for collection and interpretation of data, setup of experiment, peer reviews of publication and repetition of experiments. (Process reliabilism is not part of the scientific method, though it can be used when formulating hypothesises)

Nowhere did I say consensus is needed, I said the very opposite.

I believe consensus is the process of agreement between multiple parties, so my statement on the individual would reject consensus.

It does not reject the idea that "reliability" is subjective, which is the main point I was objecting to.  That said, I am pretty sure the OP is asking about ("consensus" over) "reliability" (of technical "processes"), not about Reliabilism, despite "reliabilism" is in the question tags...

Right, if you have to have biases, at least choose the generally helpful ones. I hope we can all agree on that!
